# Can Django run in a threaded model?

Tags: django

I was looking through the code base, particularly the database connectivity parts, and came accross this issue.

First, one gets a cursor to the database using the following stamentent:

```
from django.db import connection, transaction
cursor = connection.cursor()
```

connection is a module attribute, so in a threaded model, all threads would share that variable. Sounds a bit strange. Diving in further, the cursor() method belongs to django.db.backends.BaseDatabaseWrapper and looks like this:

```
def cursor(self):
        self.validate_thread_sharing()
        if (self.use_debug_cursor or
            (self.use_debug_cursor is None and settings.DEBUG)):
            cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
        else:
            cursor = util.CursorWrapper(self._cursor(), self)
    return cursor
```

The key is the call to _cursor(), which executes the backend code for whatever database is being used. In the case of MySQL, it executes the _cursor() method on django.db.backends.mysql.DatabaseWrapper, which looks like:

```
def _cursor(self):
    new_connection = False
    if not self._valid_connection():
        new_connection = True
        kwargs = {
            'conv': django_conversions,
            'charset': 'utf8',
            'use_unicode': True,
        }
        settings_dict = self.settings_dict
        if settings_dict['USER']:
            kwargs['user'] = settings_dict['USER']
        if settings_dict['NAME']:
            kwargs['db'] = settings_dict['NAME']
        if settings_dict['PASSWORD']:
            kwargs['passwd'] = settings_dict['PASSWORD']
        if settings_dict['HOST'].startswith('/'):
            kwargs['unix_socket'] = settings_dict['HOST']
        elif settings_dict['HOST']:
            kwargs['host'] = settings_dict['HOST']
        if settings_dict['PORT']:
            kwargs['port'] = int(settings_dict['PORT'])
        # We need the number of potentially affected rows after an
        # "UPDATE", not the number of changed rows.
        kwargs['client_flag'] = CLIENT.FOUND_ROWS
        kwargs.update(settings_dict['OPTIONS'])
        self.connection = Database.connect(**kwargs)
        self.connection.encoders[SafeUnicode] = self.connection.encoders[unicode]
        self.connection.encoders[SafeString] = self.connection.encoders[str]
        connection_created.send(sender=self.__class__, connection=self)
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
    if new_connection:
        # SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL in MySQL controls whether an AUTO_INCREMENT column
        # on a recently-inserted row will return when the field is tested for
        # NULL.  Disabling this value brings this aspect of MySQL in line with
        # SQL standards.
        cursor.execute('SET SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL = 0')
    return CursorWrapper(cursor)
```

So a new cursor is not necessarily created. If a call to _cursor() had already been made, the previously used cursor would have been returned.

In a threaded model, that means multiple threads are possibly sharing the same database cursor, which seems like a no-no.

There are also other signs that indicate that threading is not allowed in Django. This module-level code from django/db/**init**.py, from for example:

```
def close_connection(**kwargs):
    for conn in connections.all():
        conn.close()
signals.request_finished.connect(close_connection)
```

So if any request finished, all database connections are closed. What if there are concurrent requests?

Seems like a lot of stuff is being shared, which indicates that threading is not allowed. I didn't see synchronization code anywhere.

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to use threading? What's the particular use case? The normal way to achieve parallel requests is to configure the server to run in a multi-process or multi-threaded way. What are you trying to do that couldn't be done that way?

Comment: That's precisely my question. I can see one process handling one request, since different processes share nothing, but in the case of threads, I fail to understand how the issues above wouldn't create problems.